# php преобразовать целое число в px для рейтинга

Tags: php

Пытаюсь оживить звездочный рейтинг на сайте.

Вводная $star_rating всегда равна целому числу, от 10 до 100.
Пожалуйста, помогите преобразовать это число в px (css разметка),
чтобы при выводе $star_rating выводило сразу значение в px.

Не могу разобраться с этой задачей.

```
10 = 17px
20 = 34px
30 = 41px
40 = 68px
50 = 85px
60 = 102px
70 = 119px
80 = 136px
90 = 153px
100 = 170px
```

Спасибо!

Comment: так а что вы хотите увеличивать? вообще все банально создаете массив где ключ ваше значение рейтинга а значение нужные пиксели и крутите их как хотите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function rating($rating) {
  return ($rating*1.7).'px';
}
```

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 ошибку выдает

Comment: @MicroRu, идите в лог ошибок сервера и читайте.

Comment: Похоже в самой функции, если просто вставить так `<?php
function rating($rating) {
  return ($rating*1.7).'px'
}
?>` уже ошибка, что-то я не то делаю.

Comment: Точку с запятой забыл в конце return. Поправили уже, должно работать